# How to determine javafx's line chart peak location on monitor

Tags: java, javafx, charts, location

Basically, i want to display tooltip with some extra information when I hover over one of the peaks.

However, I can't guess how to get that peak's location on monitor (because tooltip asks for absolute coordinates of your monitor)

This is my current code

```
//dateNumberData is the peak

Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
//Here i just edit tooltip info
dateNumberData.getNode().setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
    tooltip.show(dateNumberData.getNode(),
        dateNumberData.getNode().localToScreen(dateNumberData.getNode().getLayoutX(), 0).getX(),
        dateNumberData.getNode().localToScreen(0, dateNumberData.getNode().getLayoutY()).getY());
    });
dateNumberData.getNode().setOnMouseExited(event -> tooltip.hide());
```

But tooltip appears all over the place. If I use `dateNumberData.getNode().getParent().localToScreen()` tooltip just doesn't appear at all (but tooltip.getX() returns kinda correct coordinates. At least it shoudld appear with those coordinates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `layoutX()` and `layoutY()` properties are not the correct ones to use here. Those *might* be the coordinates of the node in the parent, though you don't know that the node is positioned by setting those: e.g. it might use a translation or some other layout mechanism. Instead use `getBoundsInLocal()` and then transform the bounds.

It's also a good idea to add a small offset to the tooltip: this not only looks better, but it prevents the tooltip obscuring the node, which means you trigger mouse exited, and end up in a repeating loop.

```
dateNumberData.getNode().setOnMouseEntered(event -> {

    Bounds bounds = dateNumberData.getNode().localToScreen(dateNumberData.getNode().getBoundsInLocal());
    tooltip.show(dateNumberData.getNode(),
        bounds.getMaxX()+15,
        bounds.getMaxY()+5);
    });
```

Here is an SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartWithTooltip extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        series.setName("Data");
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10; i++) {
            series.getData().add(new Data<>(i, rng.nextDouble()));
        }
        chart.getData().add(series);

        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        for (Data<Number, Number> d : series.getData()) {
            d.getNode().setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
                tooltip.setText(String.format("[%d, %.3f]", d.getXValue().intValue(), d.getYValue().doubleValue()));
                Bounds nodeBounds = d.getNode().getBoundsInLocal();
                Bounds nodeBoundsInScreen = d.getNode().localToScreen(nodeBounds);
                tooltip.show(d.getNode(),
                        nodeBoundsInScreen.getMaxX()+15,
                        nodeBoundsInScreen.getMaxY()+5);
                    });
            d.getNode().setOnMouseExited(event -> tooltip.hide());
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(chart), 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I need to add some offset, i was going to add that later, but i didn't actually think that it would overlap the node and trigger `onMouseExited()` That's probably why the code with `.getParent()` didn't show any tooltips and i was getting spammed with debug output I added here...

Comment: So this solved it? Or not? I can't tell from your comment. I updated with a complete example.

Comment: Finally got time to check. And yes, it is solved. `.getParent()` + adding some offset did the trick